# interact with a pc camera using c++

Tags: c++, hardware

i intend to interact with a pc camera using c plus plus. Are there any libraries you can recommend or ways to go about ? The idea is to take shots with a Samsung wireless cam then get the images transferred unto a pc with cam and on the pc show images as per the face detection using the cam . any ideas where to start ?

Comment: @DeadMG please flag it using the close button

Comment: @Martin DeadMG doesn't have the rep needed to cast close votes.

Comment: @Anna - thanks, I thought anyone could use the new flag->off topic mechanism

Comment: @Martin Yes, but through the flag link, not close. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a wide range of ways to do it. Professional cameras have accompanying SDKs. If you camera is supported by it (I believe most webcams are) you should try [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/index.html) for a start.

Googling for "opencv face recognition" will yield plenty of hits, so you have a lot of reference material.

Try this reference ([Face and Eyes Detection Using OpenCV](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/eyes.aspx)) for a start.

After you start your project, you can specific questions on StackOverflow or on the OpenCV Yahoo! group.

Answer (score 0):

Other options are:

1) [openFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup).

Quoting from their website:

> Openframeworks is a c++ library designed to assist the creative process by providing a simple and intuitive framework for experimentation.
>
> The library is designed to work as a general purpose glue, and wraps together several commonly used libraries under a tidy interface: openGL for graphics, rtAudio for audio input and output, freeType for fonts,freeImage for image input and output, quicktime for video playing and sequence grabbing.

2) Qt

If you decide Qt, see this related question: [Displaying WebCam video with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378720/displaying-webcam-video-with-qt)